# WebView not loads images on m.facebook.com

Tags: android, facebook, android-webview

In my app there is a webview with an advertising html page in it. Some text and some pictures, all of the pictures are nicely shown.

If the user clicks on this page, the webView redirects to m.facebook.com but for some reason the page came up without any images, all of them are missing.

I tried these snippets but none of them solved my issue:

```
   mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
   mWebview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true); 
   mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
   mWebview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
   mWebview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);mWebview.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows (true);
   mWebview.getSettings().supportZoom();
   mWebview.canGoBack();
   mWebview.getSettings().setBlockNetworkImage(false);
   mWebview.getSettings().setBlockNetworkLoads(false);
   mWebview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
```

Because this app is aleady developed to iOS, i cant do it else, i must show the content in this webview.

Please help if you can!
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.0; en-us; Droid Build/ESD20) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17");
```

Answer (score 1):

I find it not work on my Nexus S running Cyanogenmod 10.1 nightly...
but since the chrome on Mac running the m.facebook.com correctly, I apply the user-agent string to the Android WebView, it works perfectly!!!

Here's the string:
**"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22"**

Is it because facebook make change to its check logic of m.facebook.com???

BTW, attach screenshot before & after changing user-agent:[image]

[image]